# NGRX return array in effect

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, effect

When I try to run below code:

```
functionMap = {
[ActionTypeEnum.TYPE_FIRST.toLowerCase()]:[getInitialDataStatus({statusType: 'disabled'}),fetchImportantDataFirst()],
[ActionTypeEnum.TYPE_SECOND.toLowerCase()]:[getInitialDataStatus({}),
                        fetchImportantDataSecond()],
[ActionTypeEnum.TYPE_THIRD.toLowerCase()]:[getInitialDataStatus({}),
                        fetchImportantDataThidr()]
}

 startMultpileActionDepensOnType$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(startMultpileActionDepensOnType),
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(selectTypeActions)),
        map(([action, select]) => {
                const actionType = select.type.toLowerCase();
                return this.unctionMap[actionType]

            }
        )
    ));
```

I got the error about:

```
TS2322: Type 'Observable<TypedAction<string>[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'. Property 'type' is missing in TypedAction<string>[].
```

But when I change to: `functionMap:{}`,

I got the error:

```
Action must have a type property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an `effect`, to retrieve multiple actions, so an array of actions, you have to use `switchMap` operator :

```js
load$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.load),
  switchMap(action => [
    actions.loadItems(),
    actions.loadHistory();
  ])
))
```

So in your case, `functionMap` returns an array of actions :

```js
startMultipleActionDepensOnType$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(startMultipleActionDepensOnType),
  withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(selectTypeActions)),
  switchMap(([action, select]) => {
    const actionType = select.type.toLowerCase();
    return this.functionMap[actionType];
  })
));
```